# I have to print a dictionary into different lines how do I do what

Tags: python, string

So I have a code there I need to print the dictionary formed into different lines and It keeps giving my error on the last line I don't know. I'm new to programming so need some help.

```
    phonebook = {}

    line = input('Name and clour: ')
    while line:
     name, number = line.split()
     phonebook[name] = number    
     line = input('Name and clour: ')
     phonebook.keys()[1]
```

Here is the error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "program.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(phonebook.keys()[1])
    TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing
```

Comment: Welcome, in order to help please post the error here as text and your python version.

Comment: `phonebook[0]` Your trying to get from a dictionary with an index.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this :

```
phonebook = {}

line = input('Name and colour: ') #I'm guessing you want them comma separated
while (len(line)>0):
    name, number = line.split(",")
    phonebook[name] = number
    print("Name : ",name," Number : ",phonebook[name])   
    line = input('Name and colour: ')

print(phonebook) # Incase you want to print the entire dictionary
```

Comment: Thank you for controbuting to this question

Comment: @vbhargav875 You might want to use a `while True:` and break out of the infinite loop when the input is not satisfying. No need to have the input code twice.

Answer (score 0):

Fixing *vbhargav875*'s answer so that the input code is not used twice.

```py
phonebook = {}

while True:
    if not (line := input("Name and colour: ")): # Empty input will exit the loop.
        break
    name, number = line.split(", ") # I'm guessing you want them comma separated.
    phonebook[name] = number
    print(f"Name: {name}, number: {phonebook[name]}.") 

print(phonebook) # In case you want to print the entire dictionary.
```